# A little confused about my issues with printing a string while inserting a score

Tags: python

I'm really new to Python and one of the things I'm struggling with is getting my code to run properly, I want it to print the current score every round but I'm having an issue adding the score into the string (Ideally not inline but if I have to I can do).
If anyone has any ideas, even if it's not specifically about the problem but instead just making the code overall more efficient, any help would be appreciated.

---

```
from random import randint
play =  1 
while play == 1:
    # Get user input & choose value
    player, opponentInt = input("Rock, Paper, or Scissors? (r/p/s)\n"), randint(1,3)
    player = player.lower()
    # Assigning player input to int value
    playerInt = []
    if player == 'r':
        playerStr, playerInt = 'Rock', 1
    elif player == 'p':
        playerStr, playerInt = 'Paper', 2
    elif player == 's':
        playerStr, playerInt = 'Scissors', 3
    # Assigning randint function input to str value
    if opponentInt == 1:
        opponentStr = 'Rock'
    elif opponentInt == 2:
        opponentStr = 'Paper'
    elif opponentInt == 3:
        opponentStr = 'Scissors'
    # Define strings
    def winStr():
        print("You chose {}, and I chose {}. Congratulations! You won! (Score = {})".format(player, opponentStr, score))
    def loseStr():
        print("You chose {}, and I chose {}. Unfortunately, you lost. (Score = {})".format(player, opponentStr, score))
    def drawStr():
        print("You chose {}, and I chose {}. It was a draw. (Score = {})".format(player, opponentStr, score))
    # Give result of game
    score = 0
    if playerInt == []:
        print('Unexpected value, please play again and check spellings.')
    elif playerInt == 1 and opponentInt == 3:
        score = score + 1
        winStr()
    elif playerInt == 3 and opponentInt == 1:
        score = score - 1
        loseStr()
    elif playerInt > opponentInt:
        score = score + 1
        winStr()
    elif playerInt < opponentInt:
        score = score - 1
        loseStr()
    elif playerInt == opponentInt:
        drawStr()
    # Ask user if they would wish to play again
    play = 2
    while play == 2:
        playAgain = input("Would you like to play again? (y/n)  ")
        playAgain = playAgain.lower()
        if playAgain == 'y':
            play = 1
        elif playAgain == 'n':
            play = 0
        else:
            play = 2
            print("Unexpected value...")
# Print score
print("Your score was {}.".format(score))
```

---

Thanks for any help.

I have tried making strings using:
`str = "String here. Score = {}".format(score)`

Along with my latest:

```
def str():
    print("String here. Score = {}".format(score))
str()
```

Comment: Don't use `str()` as a function name. Python already has a function with this name and you can break things by using the same name.

Comment: "I have tried making strings using..." What happened when you did this? What do you want to happen insstead?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice : I should clarify that I didn't actually call it str, I just used it as a placeholder term but I'll keep that in mind for future. // If the string did print, it would print but the score would always be zero no matter what I did, when I used def it just said that the function was at, and then a long hex code. Hope that clarifies everything

Answer (score 3):

You should pass these variables as arguments to your functions

```
def print_str(score):
    print("String here. Score = {}".format(score))

print_str(5)
```

As an aside you could use f-strings instead of `str.format`

```
def print_str(score):
    print(f'String here. Score = {score}')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have now fixed it and thank you to @CodyKramer for the tip in assigning formatting a string. Turned out I had an issue where the loop was resetting the variable I found after the string was actually printing the score change.

```
play = 1
while play == 1:  
    ...
    score = 0
    if ...
        score += 1
        print(score)
    ...
```

Where in fact it should have been:

```
play = 1
score = 0
while play == 1:  
    ...
    if ...
        score += 1
        print(score)
    ...
```